# How to set UITableview Height Programatically for scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

In my UITableView set the height is wrong so i can not scroll it properly..

My Code is:

```
myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 30 , width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds
v.size.height)
```

Please help me to resolve scroll issue of UITableview.

Comment: table view will be scrolled based on the content not based on the its height

Comment: What does table view contains ? is there any data in table view

Comment: Yes there are data in Tableview which is come from array

Comment: Unrelated: Why not use autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

as noted on a lot of apple docs and stackOverflow posts, do not use fixed size. 
If at beginning of iOS develop, use autolayout.

(and avoid like evil using "UIScreen.main.bounds", is "evil")

so better to add tableview on Storyboard and connect it.

see for example:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells
(more details... but very accurate.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers, that you shouldn't set a frame for the TableView but instead use autolayout.

I'd suggest checking out [this autolayout session from Stanford's iOS course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBzzfaTj4vg).